# How to put extends React Components part on this code below?

Tags: reactjs, web, web-testing

export const CreateAccount = ({ formData, setForm, navigation, submitForm}) => {
const { firstName, email, password } = formData;

at this i want to put extends React.Component but without changing all this .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a functional component. You don't need to extends from React. Component for the functional component.

Comment: but i want to use render props and const

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement more?